# Routing Error uninitialized constant ArticleController rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails and looking for a bit of assistance, I've been going around in circles with for a while, I'm getting the following error when I run localHost:3000, Routing Error uninitialized constant ArticleController, I've been editing the routes.rb to be singular to plural but it seems to have caused more issues

```
routes.rb

  Rails.application.routes.draw do
   resources :articles, :comments
    root 'articles#index'

    resources :people
    get   'entries/sign_in' => 'entries#sign_in'
    post  'entries/sign_in' => 'entries#sign_in'

    get 'assignment_2/index' => 'assignment#index'

 end
```

and my article controller is as follows

```
 article_controller

class ArticleController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @article = Article.page(params[:page]).per(25)
  end
  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if @article.update(params.require(:article).permit(:title, :company, :url))
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
  def create
    @article = Article.new(params.require(:article).permit(:title, :company, :url))
    if @article.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  def show
    @article = Article.page(params[:page]).per(25)
  end
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

end
```

the actual error is showing as

```
 NameError in ArticlesController#index
 uninitialized constant ArticlesController::Articles
 Extracted source (around line #3):

 1 class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
 2   def index
 3     @article = Articles.page(params[:page]).per(25)
 4   end
 5   def update
 6     @article = Articles.find(params[:id])


   Rails.root: C:/Users/markf/Desktop/School/RAD/RAD_Assignment_2_s9971085/Assignment_2_app
   Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

  app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:3:in `index'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'
  activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
  actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:844:in `call'
  rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
  rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
  rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
  activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
  web-console (3.6.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
 web-console (3.6.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
 web-console (3.6.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
 web-console (3.6.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
 railties (5.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
 railties (5.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
 activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
 activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
 activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
  railties (5.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
  sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
   actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
   actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
  activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
   actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
   rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
  railties (5.1.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
  puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
  puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:632:in `handle_request'
 puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:446:in `process_client'
  puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:306:in `block in run'
 puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'

 Request

  Parameters:

  None

  Toggle session dump
 Toggle env dump
  Response

  Headers:

  None
```

Above is before I renamed the articles_controller now the error message shows as follows

```
 ActionController::UnknownFormat in ArticlesController#index
 ArticlesController#index is missing a template for this request format        and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: [] NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in a web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a template, not nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If you expect 204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot.
```

Extracted source (around line #53):

```
 51
 52
 53
 54
 55
 56




           "That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot."

         raise ActionController::UnknownFormat, message
        else
         logger.info "No template found for #{self.class.name}\##{action_name}, rendering head :no_content" if logger
         super

  Rails.root: C:/Users/markf/Desktop/School/RAD/RAD_Assignment_2_s9971085/Assignment_2_app
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, like I said still learning.

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace of error?

Comment: Did you tried plural name for controller? i.e. "class ArticlesController < ApplicationController"

Answer (score 0):

Your controller name is wrong.

Rename `app/controllers/article_controller.rb` to `app/controller/articles_controller.rb`

Changed the line `class ArticleController < ApplicationController` to

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
```

Also, there is the difference between your log output and your `articles_controller.rb` file.

You should use `Article` and not `Articles`.

Model name is used in singular form and controller name in the plural form.

So, the controller will `articles_controller` but model will be `Article`.

Comment: thanks for your response, I've made those changes as suggested, though I seem to be back where I started as I'm receiving the following error **ActionController::UnknownFormat in ArticlesController#index**  raising an exception **204 no content**, I was getting this previously and couldn't rectify the problem.

Comment: Can you add the log to the question of the "EXACT" error you want to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Controllers should always be in **plural form**. If you run `bundle exec rake routes` you will see that rails is looking for example method like `articles#index`:

```
    /config/routes.rb
    resources articles
    => rake routes
     Prefix   Verb       URI Pattern                    Controller#action
     articles GET        /articles(.:format)            articles#index
              POST       /articles(.:format)            articles#create
  new_article GET        /articles/new(.:format)        articles#new
 edit_article GET        /articles/:id/edit(.:format)   articles#edit
      article GET        /articles/:id(.:format)        articles#show
              PUT        /articles/:id(.:format)        articles#update
              DELETE     /articles/:id(.:format)        articles#destroy
```

So these changes should fix the problem:
- Rename your controller file `article_controller.rb` -> `articles_controller.rb`;
- Rename your controller class name `ArticleController` -> `ArticlesController`.

Comment: and shlensky I've made those changes as suggested though still receiving the following **NameError in ArticlesController#index** **uninitialized constant ArticlesController::Articles**

Comment: I didn't notice that. In Rails Models are in single form. So you have to call Article.new , Article.find and so on. Also the model file should be named article.rb and the class should be named Article. Can you provide a github URL where I can see the code because I got confused. Your error shows that you call `Articles.new` but in the code that you shared from the controller it is `Article.new`.

Comment: the code is on bitbucket  'https://Mark_Forcina@bitbucket.org/Mark_Forcina/rad18_assign_2_indiv_s9971085.git' I think I've fixed the discrepancies in the naming though still getting the above error **ActionController::UnknownFormat in ArticlesController#index**

Comment: But @Markyfor this is completely new error. Now that code in the controller is executed but your rendering is not OK. Which means the first problem is solved but now you have to read more about the methods in the controller :)